# Kafka server not running on windows after zookepeer successfully running on port 2181

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am following these link:http://programming-tips.in/kafka-set-up-apache-kafka-on-windows/ and https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os for Apache Kafka setup on a local machine.

After successfully running zookeeper for which my screen looks like:
[image: ![Zookeper server running on command prompt]
[image]

My server.properties file looks like:

```
log.dirs="C:\Program Files\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\kafka-logs"
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

My zookeeper.properties file looks like:

```
dataDir="C:\Program Files\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\zookeeper-data"
clientPort=2181
```

But, when I am trying to run the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat \config\server.properties
```

Although, I have give all the paths correct which I have verified many times, I get this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka on Windows currently doesn't support spaces in the install path. Try moving your Kafka folder so the path does not contain spaces. This issue is reported in a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4860), and should be fixed in one of the upcoming releases.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be with leading '\' in your path, the following should work

```
C:\Program Files\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
```

Comment: I tried this command too. Now, the error is different which is: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.